# PHP/MySQL Assigning category based on category with least responses

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on building a website to be used in a social science experiment. After completing a form a user will be assigned two treatments.  So that all treatments are responded to equally I want to assign the user with the treatment which has the lowest number of responses.

After the treatments have been selected the script should + 1 to the response field and update the database accordingly, as well as updating the record for the user with the treatments that have been assigned.

After this the user should be sent to a page depending on the "treat1" that they have been assigned.

I have written the following code, however it does not seem to perform any functions, other than redirecting the user to treatment0.html

```
<?php

session_start();

//Connect to Database 
$con = mysql_connect("db.host.com","user","password");
if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could Not Connect: ' .mysql_error());
    }


//Select Database   
mysql_select_db("myDB", $con);


//Get treatment id's and store in SESSION variables
$_SESSION['treat1'] = mysql_query("SELECT TOP 1 treat1_id FROM treatment1 ORDER BY response ASC");
$_SESSION['treat2'] = mysql_query("SELECT TOP 1 treat2_id FROM treatment2 ORDER BY response ASC");


//Add 1 to response field in treatment databases
mysql_query("UPDATE treatment1 SET RESPONSE='RESPONSE + 1' WHERE treat1_id = ".$_SESSION['treat1']."");
mysql_query("UPDATE treatment2 SET RESPONSE='RESPONSE + 1' WHERE treat2_id = ".$_SESSION['treat2']."");


//Update user record with assigned treatments
mysql_query("UPDATE user SET TREAT1=".$_SESSION['treat1']." , TREAT2=".$_SESSION['treat2']." WHERE email = 'email@address.com'");

//Send user to page based on treat1_id
if ($_SESSION['treat1'] == 0)
        $url = 'treatment0.html';
elseif ($_SESSION['treat1'] == 1)
    $url = 'treatment1.html';
else
    $url = 'treatment2.html';        

    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">'; 


//Close connection
mysql_close($con);


?>
```

Dreamweaver hasn't given any syntax errors and when I run the script and it doesn't throw any errors but does not perform any of the functions that I was expecting it to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why are you storing the treatment ids in the session?

Comment: I am new to PHP and they are needed later on so I thought it would be better to store them in session rather than query the database again.

Comment: ok then continue using sessions I guess unless someone comes up with a better method. Try putting $con at the end of the query, example: `mysql_query("QUERY CONTENT", $con);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't **mysql_query** return a resource or **FALSE** at first place?

[PHP.net description](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: Thank's for the help.  I have it working now by passing the result of the query to mysql_fetch_array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$treatment1 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM treatment1 ORDER BY response ASC LIMIT 1");
$treatment2 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM treatment2 ORDER BY response ASC LIMIT 1");


//Add 1 to response field in treatment databases
mysql_query("UPDATE treatment1 SET RESPONSE='RESPONSE + 1' WHERE treat1_id = $treatment1");
mysql_query("UPDATE treatment2 SET RESPONSE='RESPONSE + 1' WHERE treat2_id = $treatment2");


//Update user record with assigned treatments
mysql_query("UPDATE user SET TREAT1 = '$treatment1' , TREAT2 = '$treatment2' WHERE email = 'email@address.com'");

//Send user to page based on treat1_id
if ($treament1 == 0)
        $url = 'treatment0.html';
elseif ($treatment == 1)
    $url = 'treatment1.html';
else
    $url = 'treatment2.html';        

    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
```